# YouTube search API returns different results to a manual search on YouTube

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am using the YouTube v3 API to search for videos. In some cases, the results returned from the API are completely different to the results I get when using exactly the same query string   manually on the YouTube site.
Please can anybody explain why this would happen

For example search for "Zombie Hunting Stiletto Style Spring Assisted Open Pocket Knife"

Via the API the first 10 results are :

```
Iulyke14P7c
vCjOCf20Uv8
gKNBLil4_uk
0eKNL-dQR_Q
PL0sC12k5-U
GGjHrmw-4Kc
ylLsWVcLh-w
QEn_ysLPdUI
Ds7XwIBgI6Q
NXuxKtcsSik
```

Manually on YouTube front end, the first 10 results are :

```
LstcGDEAsWw
Iulyke14P7c
dXPjpUvJkaA
_wYuBvvS63w
SVdwocDkZL0
HwNJgu8UCtM
vCjOCf20Uv8
Ok3jlNBr1bc
mRq4eapV1wk
1T93YAMQ5V0
```

Only 2 are the same (but at different position) the rest are all different

Thanks

Comment: with examples it's would be better for us

Answer (score 1):

I try with your example.

Well it depends with the options you chose in the API. There is so much options like :

```
location
order
publishedAfter
publishedBefore
type 
...
```

Yopu can find all the options on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

"**the Youtube search**" has his options, and you need to chose your options in the API. 
Understand the "search" of YouTube is not so simple. My guess, they use lots of options regarding your last videos that you seen,  your country etc etc.

But basically, the resultat is corresponding with what you want. There is no weird things, you just need to take the good options regarding what you want in your app.

Comment: In the API, I am not specifying any options right now I am using the defaults. There is no special options that I want, all I want is the same or at least more than 20% the same results as if I searched via YouTube. When I search via YouTube, I made sure to be logged out, so it cannot be using my user information, and I have also tried from different computers, in different locations, and the results are still different to the API results

Comment: You don't try in the good way. If you try with differents computers, see if the results are the same or not in the YouTube Search. Second point, youtube search doesn't use the defaults options. You need to try and find them yourself. You ask why the results are different between the API and YouTube Search ? I thinks you have the answer. Now we are not here to tell you which options you need to choose,  for having the exact same content between api and youtube, because YouTube use a lots with different configurations.