# Youtube API vs youtube,com search - BIG DIFFERENT - Why?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I know that the youtube API search gives different results from the youtube.com search. However, i suspect that the API is a lot more sensitive to typo:

Here are a few examples:

- 11a or 2b 100 balkan beat box hermetico
- hermetico 05
- hermetico balkan beat box 02 hermetico

In youtube.com, they all include the video youtubeId 8Psuqys26J4, which i wish to find . They find it in their top 10 (and even better).
However, the API youtube search does not find them at all in the first 50 results.

I did use proxy to London, as my server is in West Europe using incognito. I would'nt mind if the order was different, but i cannot find any parameters for youtube's API to make it show the "right" result too.

Here are my current parameters, nothing fancy:

```
      searchStr: dbSong.filteredFileName,
      part:'snippet', // didnt matter much
      type: 'video', // didnt matter much
      maxResults : 50,
      // regionCode : "IL", // didnt matter much
      // order: "viewCount", // didnt matter much
```

Is there anything i can do to make yourtube API to be more "forgiving" for changes in the search text like youtube.com?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YouTube search API returns different results to a manual search on YouTube](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158026/youtube-search-api-returns-different-results-to-a-manual-search-on-youtube)

Comment: I agree that it is a similar issue, however i point to a specific difference between the API and the youtube.com of small changes that ruins only one of them. Since i could not find a solution there and it is not exactly the same issue, i was hoping someone might know something about my more specific problem.